# What does Java byte code look like?

Tags: java, binary, jvm, byte, bytecode

On the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode#Instructions it says Java byte code looks like this:

```
0:   iconst_2
1:   istore_1
2:   iload_1
3:   sipush  1000
6:   if_icmpge       44
9:   iconst_2
10:  istore_2
11:  iload_2
12:  iload_1
13:  if_icmpge       31
```

I thought that Java byte code was executed like a series of integers in hexadecimal or binary?

Comment: That is the textual representation of the byte code.

Comment: Open a classfile in a hex editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What Wikipedia shows is the "[assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembler_%28computing%29#Assembler)" for a JVM. Not the "[machine code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)" for a JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Java is compiled from `.java` files to `.class` files. The `.class` files consist of a bunch of bytecodes. Bytecode is to Java what assembler is to C++. Each bytecode is a number no larger than a byte and has a mnemonic. The numbers and their mnemonic are what you have listed in your question.